# Which async call use for DB connection and still responsive GUI?--

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

My application connects to MySQL but sometimes it takes a while and the GUI is getting frozen. I would like to do the connection on the other thread, I guess BeginInvoke would be the best way (I know about background worker but I would like to learn this). I have studied MSDN page but I did not understand what is the best way to use?
They also say that you can use only callback when the thread that called the async.method does not need to know the results...I dont understand it as I believe I can set some variable in the other thread to "pass" the result well.
I would just need the GUI to be not frozen while the connection is being established. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest way to handle it is to use a BackgoundWorker. It is specifically designed to take care of most threading issues such as marshalling progress events and completion notices from the background thread to the GUI thread. I've used it to great success with both WinForms and WPF.

I know many other methods for doing this, but they all take two or three attempts for me to get right.